# How to add permission in qt after android 6

Tags: android, qt, qt-creator, android-permissions

I added permission for read from storage in androidManifest but still i cant read from file. I understand after android 6 except manifest we should get permission. How can i do that in qt?

Answer (score 2):

https://forum.qt.io/topic/72497/android-6-0-sdcard-write-permission/3

> are you talking about the Android M runtime permissions? This is added
>   in Qt 5.8 as private API and will become public in Qt 5.9. See
>   [QTBUG-50759](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-50759)

---

article describing more about android runtime permission in qt: http://www.bytran.org/androidmpermissions.htm